# vertical ScrollBar in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, tablelayoutpanel

I want to be able to scroll inside a `TableLayoutPanel` if the content gets higher than the panel itself.
I have tried:

- Set `AutoScroll` to `true` (adds [unnecessary horizontal scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805351/net-scrollbar-autoscroll-problem))
- Additionally add Padding on the right to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing (leaves a nasty gap between content and scrollbar)
- set `AutoScroll` to `false` and `VerticalScroll.Visible` to `true` (the scrollbar ignores when the content grows and doesn't allow the user to scroll)

**How can I get a pleasant vertical scrollbar without nasty side effects?**

---

some runnable code to play with:

```
public class FormTLPTest : Form
{
    TableLayoutPanel tlp;

    public FormTLPTest()
    {
        Height = 800;
        Width = 800;

        tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tlp.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
        //tlp.AutoScroll = true;  //adds horizontal ScrollBar
        //tlp.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 0); //prevents horizontal ScrollBar but adds nasty gap
        tlp.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100.0F));

        Controls.Add(tlp);

        tlp.Click += Tlp_Click;

        Add10Lines();
    }

    private void Tlp_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Add10Lines();
    }

    private void Add10Lines()
    {
        tlp.SuspendLayout();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Label lb2 = new Label();
            lb2.Margin = new Padding();
            lb2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lb2.BackColor = Color.White;
            lb2.Text = "Some longer Text - it contains information. Don't know what I should write to fill the space";

            lb2.Click += Tlp_Click;

            tlp.Controls.Add(lb2, 0, i);
        }

        tlp.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted works for me, just set autoscroll to true and then  `tlp.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;`

EDIT: 
Just noticed the horizontal bar anyway, my resolution hidden it. Anyway, set the autoscroll to false, then add
`tlp.AutoScroll = true;`
after 
`tlp.ResumeLayout();` in Add10Lines() method.

Comment: the advice in the edit also doesn't hide the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/iGSGshM) The Enabled part does nothig. Strange, the bar's showing for me for a moment, then it's not visible.

Comment: Awsome! I missed still setting the vertical scrollbar to visibile

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to set the Height of the HorizontalScroll to something bigger than the container.

what I want to say is that if the height of **TableLayoutPanel** is 300 make the height of the Scroll 350.

Try adding the height to the Scroll that should be greater than **TableLayoutPanel** height

Answer (score 0):

You are using the below line in your code, and due to it you are not getting a vertical scrollbar:

```
tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Instead of using that, try the below line, which may work for you:

```
tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```